# Can seaborn and networkx be integrated into GUI via matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, seaborn, subplot

Using the code below, I can plot basic matplotlib plots in a gui designed in pyqt5 (such as giving it a list of xs and ys and it plots the points). However, I cannot plug in advanced modules such as seaborn or networkx (lets focus on seaborn) that utilize the plotting functionality of matplotlib to display the data you generate with the functions.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 110, 391, 311))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 40, 231, 61))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 180, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Graphitdude)

    def Graphitdude(self):
        Lister3 = pd.read_csv("Betadata.csv",index_col=[0])#just a collection of labels and assorted correlation values ranging from 0 to 1 to be constructed into a heatmap.
        plot = sns.heatmap(Lister3) # This is the problematic function, it does it, and I can display it IN LINE but not in the gui canvas? 
        plt.yticks(rotation=0)
        self.widget.canvas.ax.plot()#if passed discreet x and y values, it graphs it, but it doesnt like to pass the seaborn figure?
        self.widget.canvas.draw()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:24pt; font-weight:600;\">Test</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

from mplwidget import MplWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mplwidget.py is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
import matplotlib


matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')

# Matplotlib canvas class to create figure
class MplCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        Canvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        Canvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        Canvas.updateGeometry(self)

# Matplotlib widget
class MplWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)   # Inherit from QWidget
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()                  # Create canvas object
        self.vbl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()         # Set box for plotting
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

My best idea is that these functions are designing their own matplotlib figure (or subplot, not sure), and this figure cannot be supplied to the widget code by the methods I have tried.

sns.heatmap(xxxx) returns "ax", which should be able to be used by the mplwidget.py script, right? Can I pass these to the canvas to display seaborn graphics?

Comment: Hi, an interesting question but from this: `I cannot plug in advanced modules`, it's a bit difficult to understand what exact problems you're facing. Could you please elaborate? My guess is that you can take canvass of _any_ figure, including the ones generated with seaborn or networkx, and then push that canvass wherever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

> **seaborn.heatmap(data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, center=None, robust=False, annot=None, fmt='.2g', annot_kws=None, linewidths=0, linecolor='white', cbar=True, cbar_kws=None, cbar_ax=None, square=False, xticklabels='auto', yticklabels='auto', mask=None, ax=None, **kwargs)**
>
> [...]
>
> **ax** : matplotlib Axes, optional
>
> Axes in which to draw the plot, otherwise use the currently-active Axes.

So then you should just pass the `AxesSubplot` of `MplCanvas` as parameter ax:

```
def Graphitdude(self):
    Lister3 = pd.read_csv("Betadata.csv",index_col=[0])
    plot = sns.heatmap(Lister3, ax=self.widget.canvas.ax) 
    plt.yticks(rotation=0)
    self.widget.canvas.draw()
```

*I have used many functions similar to `heatmap` and always provide that parameter.*

Comment: This solution works great, but having to use the MplCanvas is creating a small problem with clearing out the axis elements? (I generate a new legend for each plot, and cannot figure out how to clear it out) I can plot the heatmap itself several times from different data sets, but each time it generates a new axis element to put the legend in. How can I "reset" the entire MplCanvas?